# Página contactos Preenchida através de Excel

Tags: html, microsoft-excel

Estou a criar uma página de internet e gostaria de saber se o que quero é possivel. 
Tenho uma página que contem contactos

```
<tr>
<td>Teste - 123456789</td>
<td>Teste - 987456123</td>
</tr>
```

Isto Varias vezes e as vezes é necessário actualizar com entrada ou saída de algum trabalhador. 
Uma vez que tenho estes contactos por ordem alfabética torna-se chato ter de ordenar tudo novamente.
O que gostaria de saber é se por exemplo tendo um ficheiro em Excel com esses dados todos ele actualizar a página através dele.

Comment: Você tem uma página estática onde é tudo atualizado manualmente?

Comment: Se não tiver PHP ou outro servidor, pode utilizar esse script: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: Estou a criar e agora estou a pensar numa hipótese melhor para alterar isso. 
A pagina só tem html e css.

Comment: Qual é a forma de eu conseguir atualizar os dados?